# Github actions run jobs in webserver container unable to connect to localhost

Tags: docker, apache, github-actions, cicd

I have a container which starts a webserver when I run the container on my laptop, login to its terminal and do a curl request to 127.0.0.1 it will give a result. When I try the same thing in a GitHub Actions Workflow I get: "curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused". I have tried things like adding ports (which I do not think should be necessary) but it won't work. I actually think apache is not running for some reason but I do not understand why as it does work locally.

See a minimal workflow file below:

```
name: Auto tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master", "githubActions" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: php:7.4.33-apache-bullseye
    steps:
      - name: GET localhost
        run: curl 127.0.0.1
```

I am expecting I get something like:

```
# curl localhost
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access this resource.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.54 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

But I get "curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused" instead.

Comment: How did you export port 80 and what was the error? Please include that in your question. Thanks!

Comment: There was no error, just same result. The docker image does EXPOSE 80 and in the workflow i've tried with 
      ports:
        - 80
and - 80:80

Comment: I just realized that you are running `steps` inside the `container`, not side by side. What you're looking for is `services`. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers.

Answer (score 0):

You are running `steps` inside the container, not alongside it. See [Running jobs in a container](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/running-jobs-in-a-container#exposing-network-ports-on-a-container). That's why there's no server running there and `curl` fails.

What you're looking for is [`jobs.<job_id>.services`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idservices). See [About service containers](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers) for more details.

---

With `services`, a sample workflow will be:

```yaml
name: php_container

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      php:
        image: php:7.4.33-apache-bullseye
        ports:
        - 80:80
    steps:
    - name: Test
      run: curl localhost
```

---

Apart from that, if using [php:7.4.33-apache-bullseye](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/php/7.4.33-apache-bullseye/images/sha256-18b3497ee7f2099a90b66c23a0bc3d5261b12bab367263e1b40e9b004c39e882?context=explore) is not a hard requirement on your side, you can simply avoid the `container` or `services` altogether and use the preinstalled [PHP](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#php-tools) and [Apache Web Server](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#web-servers). The default preinstalled Apache is inactive so you'll have to start it.

Comment: Thanks but I did try with services (have mysql and redis running like that) but now I needed my working repository in there as well. 

I did figure out the apache server was actually not running and fixed it by starting it so it is working now. I just don't understand why apache is starting when I run the docker image on my laptop but its not starting when I run it in github actions.

Comment: @sanderdev: Please post an answer too with all the details of how you fixed it. I'd like to look at your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, we just need to start apache. Like I said I just don't get what the difference is from running it on my laptop versus running it on a github runner. So i've added two commands in the run part just before curl localhost: "apache2ctl start &" and "sleep 1".

Comment: @sanderdev: Got it. That's how you run multiple processes in a container i.e. run others in the background. See layer # 30 of [php:7.4.33-apache-bullseye](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/php/7.4.33-apache-bullseye/images/sha256-18b3497ee7f2099a90b66c23a0bc3d5261b12bab367263e1b40e9b004c39e882?context=explore) for linux/amd64. It runs the Apache in the foreground and that's what you observe when it's run directly. In your workflow, all the commands are run inside the container so the shell control is available for you instead of layer # 30's `CMD`. IMO, `services` is better for this case.

Comment: @sanderdev: Apart from that, if using that specific container image is not a restriction on your side, you can simply avoid `container` and `services` altogether and use the preinstalled [PHP](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#php-tools) and [Apache Web Server](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#web-servers). The default preinstalled Apache is inactive so you'll have to start it.

Comment: thank you for clarifying running the process in the foreground, I wasn't aware of this. And I will try your alternative to just use the runner, I am happy my current solution works but it feels a bit hacky.